# Validity of a number in a cell

Tags: excel, validation

I have a members table in excel with a column for cell phone numbers, and I need to output members with cell phone numbers that are invalid (less/more than 10 digits).

Can anyone suggest the best way of doing this?

Is there a formula to count number of digits in a cell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your RegEx:

```
/(?:(?<= [+][1-9])|(?<= [1-9])|(?<= ))([2-9][0-9]{9})\b/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function IsValidPhone(xlCell as Range) as Boolean    
  If (xlCell.range Like "#[-.]###[-.]###[-.]###") OR
     (xlCell.range2 Like "#[-.]###[-.]###[-.]###") 
  Then
    IsValidPhone = True
  ELSE
    IsValidPhone = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),LEN(A1)=10)
```

This will test if cell a1 is number and has length of 10 digits.
You can drag it down and the filter all the False.
If you have other valid characters like "-" then add them to your OP and we will deal with it too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **VBA Macro/Function** in a project or global **`Module`**.  If you don't have one, then simply create/add one (it will be called **Module1** by default - that's fine.)

Then Create the function below.  Then pass a `reg` parameter like `"(?<!\S)(?:\+?1)?([2-9]\d{9})(?!\S)"` which does the following:

```
(?<! \S )            //  Look behind, whitespace or ^   
(?: \+? 1 )?         //  Optional +1  
( [2-9] \d{9} )      //  (1), ten digit phone  
(?! \S )             //  Look ahead, whitespace or $
```

---

```
'// Executes a Regular Expression on a provided string 
'// and returns a selected submatch:
'//    `str` - string to execute the regex on
'//    `reg` - the regular expression with at least 1 capture '()'  
'//    `matchIndex` - the index of the match you want to return (default: 0)  
'//    `subMatchIndex` - the index of the submatch you want to return (default: 0)  
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function RegexExecute( _
  str As String, reg As String, Optional matchIndex As Long, _
  Optional subMatchIndex As Long _
) As String  

  On Error GoTo ErrHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = reg
    regex.Global = Not (matchIndex = 0 And subMatchIndex = 0) '//For efficiency
    If regex.test(str) Then
      Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
      RegexExecute = matches(matchIndex).SubMatches(subMatchIndex)
      Exit Function
    End If 

  ErrHandl:
    RegexExecute = CVErr(xlErrValue) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-VBA formula solution that ignores phone number formatting and will get the number of digits in a cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},"")))
```

For example, it will run successfully on all of the below:

```
1234567890
123-456-7890
(123)4567890
(123) 456-7890
123.456.7890
123 456 7890
```